# showing wrong icon/splash screen on Windows Phone - cordova/phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, icons, splash-screen

Just got a rejection from the Windows Store policy team because...
'10.1 App Icon Generic or Unrepresentative'

I believe i know what the issue is becuase i downloaded the App onto my phone and on Windows phone the tile icon, splash screen and icon in the app list is showing as a generic cordova logo like this...
https://cordova.apache.org/images/cordova_256.png

Where its meant to use these...
https://github.com/CarlRyds/CraftingGuideforMinecraft/tree/master/www/res

The right icons show on Android (tried it on a samsung galaxy s4) but not windows phone (nokia lumia 520), heres my config.xml file, to me all the code looks right, but maybe i'm missing something?...

https://github.com/CarlRyds/CraftingGuideforMinecraft/blob/master/config.xml

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a late response to your question but can you try Cleaning your project in Visual Studio? In `Build` -> `Clean` and then rebuild and deploy. This worked for me for the app icon for example when it wasn't updating.